# Pygal bar chart says "No Data"

Tags: pygal

I am trying to create a bar graph in pygal that uses the api for github and charts the most popular projects based on stars. I posted my code below, but I cannot figure out why my graph keep saying "No Data"??? Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS

url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'
r = requests.get(url)
print("Status code:", r.status_code)

response_dict = r.json()
print('Total repositories:', response_dict['total_count'])

repo_dicts = response_dict['items']


names,stars = [],[]
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])

my_style = LS('#333366',base_style=LCS)
chart = pygal.Bar(style=my_style,x_label_rotation=45,show_legend=False)
chart.title = 'Most Starred Python Projects on GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names
chart.add = ('',stars)
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

Answer (score 1):

on the second last line of your code, chart.add=('',stars) there should not be a '=' equal sign there , it should be chart.add('',stars) then the code should work! :)